# CheckPasswordASync returns false always

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a custom IdentityUser.  I can call `_userManager.FindByNameAsync`every time and it returns the user details.  Following this, if i call `_userManager.CheckPasswordASync` it always returns false.  It strangely works fine in my localhost development, but does not when deployed to a webserver.

custom user class:

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FistName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Register Service:

```
services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, IdentityRole>(
     option =>
            {
              option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
              option.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
              option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
              option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
              option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
              option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            }
            ).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Login Class:

```
[Route("login")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
{
     var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
     var test = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);

     return Ok(test);
}
```

Comment: Check your database for production to see whether the username and password are right.

Comment: I can register a user fine, the issue is not the connection string

Comment: Try to add a new action which contains the method to create the username and `CheckPasswordAsync`, will it return false?